# How to remove "Share with Skype" from the Windows Explorer context menu

Tags: windows-explorer, skype, context-menu

In a recent update a new `Share with Skype` context menu item has appeared. How can this item be removed?

[image]

PS: There is some information here, but it's not complete: https://www.reddit.com/r/skype/comments/fkxbhw/q_context_menu_share_with_skype/

Answer (score 49):

In case you are using the Skype App, removing the context menu item is trickier.

One way is to delete `DllPath` under

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PackagedCom\Package\Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.61.100.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c\Class\{776DBC8D-7347-478C-8D71-791E12EF49D8}
```

However updates to the app will probably restore this. Adding the following `REG_SZ` key

`"{776DBC8D-7347-478C-8D71-791E12EF49D8}"="Skype"`

to

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked]`

is probably a good idea. Restart Windows to take effect.

[image: Blocking Skype Explorer extension]

---

Comment: Confirm adding the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked` key (of type `REG_SZ`) works on Windows 10, build 18362.959. Restart is required.

Comment: After new updates kept reenabling it under different key names, I was beginning to get tired of removing it every time. Adding it to the ```Blocked``` list removed it permanently for me on Win10  version 2004. And, you don't need to restart the computer; simply restarting ```explorer.exe``` is enough.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on Win10 20H2 on skype 8.66.0.77

Comment: I think the class ref changed to {F2CC526B-08C7-4E0E-BA62-74A53C4AB446}, but that does not work for me. (Perhaps I have to restart).

Comment: @Ajasja I actually had 2 entries in my context menu. The above solution removed one for me. I tried your suggestion but allas, no luck even after a restart. I'm running Win 10 x64 20H2 after a clean install so no previous versions were present on this system.

Comment: @Ajasja Same for me, it works for only 5 seconds after I restart the explorer.

Answer (score 37):

**Yet another update:** Works in Windows 11 too.

**Update:** Works in Windows 10 version 21H1 too.

Original answer:
As of Windows 10 version 2004, you can do the following to remove the "Share with Skype" from the context menu:

1. Run the following `REG ADD` command in an elevated cmd:

   ```
   REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked" /v {776DBC8D-7347-478C-8D71-791E12EF49D8} /d Skype
   ```
2. Restart the Explorer process through Task Manager to see the effect. You do not need to restart Windows.

<sup>* Based on the answer given by [Ajasja](https://superuser.com/a/1569321/401935). So all credits go to him. I merely created the REG command.</sup>

Comment: Worked on Windows 10 version 20H2. Use CMD, not powershell.

Answer (score 24):

On Windows 8 (and Windows 10?), RegEdit found the entry at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ShareWithSkype`

Deleted that, and the item disappeared from the context menu immediately - no need to reboot / log out.

No need to mess with [ShellExView 2.01](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) because Skype did not show up there anyway.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see that entry  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ept6f.png on windows 10.

Comment: At some point between April and July, Microsoft changed the way this works. Also see the answer from @Ajasja if this does not work for you.

Comment: Instead of deleting it I left the "folder" ShareWithSkype, deleted the items inside except the `(Default)` and changed the permissions excluding the user account. When skype updates it raises a warning but it can be ignored (there's an Ignore button) and the context menu is clean after the update!

Comment: I can confirm this works on Windows 10 too. I think it depends if you are running the Desktop app or the UWP app from the Windows Store. I was running the full desktop app.

Comment: Worked for me, WIN 10 22h2 (os build 19045.3996)

Answer (score 10):

There are two main entries for "Share with Skype" in registry.

- To disable one from `Skype for Desktop` use following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ShareWithSkype]
"LegacyDisable"=""
```

Method above survives reinstall. It also survives install if `.reg` file is merged before installation, so hopefully will survive updates too.
Deleting Skype via Control Panel also wipes this tweak, so manual reinstall requires `.reg` file to be merged again after deletion/installation.

- To disable another one from `Skype for Windows 10` use following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked]
"{776DBC8D-7347-478C-8D71-791E12EF49D8}"="Skype"
```

Comment: THANK YOU SIR, top answer! I did have them both, first tried the other solutions mentioned above but I kept with 1 remaining...now they're both gone. You made my day :)

Answer (score 4):

The location has changed to:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PackagedCom\Package\Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.61.87.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c\Class\{776DBC8D-7347-478C-8D71-791E12EF49D8}
```

Manually delete the `DllPath` value in the Registry Editor. Note that as the application updates it may change so take note of the path and look for a similaur GUID.

Comment: Testing this out now

Comment: Worked immediately without logoff or reboot... however: it came back a week later with a different path after Skype auto-updated. (Now `Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.63.76.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c` instead of `Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.61.87.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c`.)

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff I also had this behaviour. I understand it to appear with skype for business updates.. if they even update that anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Just a reminder, that uninstalling Skype will of course also fix the issue.